# Is deliverying halal food for a restaurant permissible when it also sells haram food?

Tags: halal-haram, work

I currently work with a Food Delivery Service .

My Question is : If I only deliver orders which contain no Swine or Alcohol, would my income be Halal? Even if the restaurants I deliver from sells Alcohol And Swine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are not contributing in the sale of the Haram items, or not profiting from them, your income would surely be Halal. It can be seen that almost all the companies and brands nowadays are linked to some kind of Haram business, but as long as you are not contributing in it, you're good.
 الله أعلم.